# Check if worksheet exist using infragistics

Tags: c#, excel, infragistics

i need to check if a worksheet exist in excel and if not, to create it. I'm using infragistics and the following code gives me the following error:

> use of unassigned local variable 'workSheet'.

this is the code:

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
 Worksheet workSheet;
 foreach (Something result in results)
  {            
     foreach (Something item in result.Something)
     {
         if (!workbook.Worksheets.Exists(item.GetType().Name))
         {
             workSheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add(item.GetType().Name);
         }
         // cell font
        IWorkbookFont oFont = workSheet.Workbook.CreateNewWorkbookFont();
....
    }
}
```

The error is about the: `IWorkbookFont oFont = workSheet.Workbook.CreateNewWorkbookFont()`

on the workSheet variable.

thanks.

Comment: To avoid this error, initialize worksheet to null when you declare it. Then check if worksheet is null before you create a new font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can avoid the error. Initialize worksheet to null when you declare it. Do not forget the null check before accessing the worksheet.

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
Worksheet workSheet = null;
foreach (Something result in results)
{            
     foreach (Something item in result.Something)
     {
         if (!workbook.Worksheets.Exists(item.GetType().Name))
         {
             workSheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add(item.GetType().Name);
         }

         if (workSheet != null)
         {

             // cell font
             IWorkbookFont oFont = workSheet.Workbook.CreateNewWorkbookFont();
             ....
         }
        ....
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer:

```
  Worksheet workSheet = null;
 if (!workbook.Worksheets.Exists(item.GetType().Name))
                {
                    workSheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add(item.GetType().Name);
                }
                else
                {
                    workSheet = workbook.Worksheets[item.GetType().Name];
                }
                // cell font
                IWorkbookFont oFont = workSheet.Workbook.CreateNewWorkbookFont();
```

I had to make sure the workSheet variable has values (initialized).